# Cron не выполняет скрипт Python 3

Tags: python, cron, postfix, crontab

Вот что в логах `syslog`:

```
CRON[13315]: (root) CMD (cd /home/user/insta-mary/ && python3 ./post.py > /home/user/insta-mary/log)
postfix/pickup[13044]: 92A7B42D48: uid=0 from=<root>
postfix/cleanup[13277]: 92A7B42D48: message-id=<20170125150801.92A7B42D48@br.com>
postfix/qmgr[10403]: 92A7B42D48: from=<root@br.com>, size=2216, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
postfix/local[13279]: 92A7B42D48: to=<root@br.com>, orig_to=<root>, relay=local, delay=0.17, delays=0.11/0/0/0.06, dsn=2.$
postfix/qmgr[10403]: 92A7B42D48: removed
```

Сами логи `/home/user/insta-mary/log` чисты.

Может нужно прочесть что пишет postfix. Но я не понимаю как. Подскажите пожалуйста.

PS: Есть несколько других Python скриптов, которые работают корректно через `cron`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

укажите полный путь к выполняемой программе.

т.е., не `python3`, а (например) `/usr/bin/python3`. точный путь к нужной программе можно узнать с помощью программы `which`:

```
$ which python3
```

> Сами логи `/home/user/insta-mary/log` чисты.

в подобных случаях имеет смысл перенаправлять не только *stdout*, но и *stderr*. т.е. вместо

```
программа > файл
```

писать:

```
программа > файл 2>&1
```

---

переменные окружения в ваших пользовательских сеансах оболочки существенно отличаются от переменных окружения в сеансах оболочки, запускаемых программой *crond*. если вашей программе требуется наличие каких-то особенных переменных окружения, вы можете добавить их в редактируемый *crontab*-файл (лучше в самом начале):

```
переменная=значение
```

посмотреть все переменные окружения (и их значения) можно с помощью программы `env`. ту же программу можно использовать и в *crontab*-файле, перенаправив её вывод в какой-нибудь файл:

```
env > /tmp/какой-нибудь-файл
```

Comment: Про полный путь знал, это не помогало. Про логи ошибок спасибо, понял в чем была проблема. Отсутствие модуля `imageio` `imageio.plugins.ffmpeg.download()`. Хотя это странно, ведь он был скачал до этого, и скрипт выполняется от пользователя. Видимо это из-за `cron`. Не подскажите в чем может быть причина, или лучше создать новый вопрос?)

Comment: дополнил ответ.