# Не работает скрипт на bash из крона

Tags: bash, cron, docker

Имеется скрипт на bash, от себя он выполняется, а вот по крону почему то переменная line записывается пустой.

```
container="name"
hostname=$(hostname)
space="$(docker exec -it $container df -h | awk '{printf $1 ":" $4 "\n"}' )"

arr=()
while read -r line; do
   arr+=("${hostname}:${container}:${line}")
done <<< "$space"

printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}" >> freediskspace 2>&1
```

cron:
    */1 *   * * *   root    cd /opt/scripts/ && /bin/bash freedisk.sh

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/619383/178576 // и переведите, пожалуйста, вопрос на русский язык.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

решено! Сделал в кроне перенаправление вывода ошибок в файл. В файле было, "tty is not a tty with docker exec". Чтобы это решить убрал -t в при запуске докера, то есть получилось следующее docker exec -i ....

Answer (score 2):

Для начала файл нужно сделать исполняемым:

```
chmod +x /opt/scripts/freedisk.sh
```

потом хорошо бы указать как исполнять скрипт с помощью:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

это прописывается в самом начале скрипта ещё пару правок и результат:

```
#!/bin/bash
container="name"
hostname=$(hostname)
space="$(docker exec -it $container df -h | awk '{printf $1 ":" $4 "\n"}' )"

arr=()
while read line; do
   arr+=("${hostname}:${container}:${line}")
done < $space

printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}" >> freediskspace 2>&1
```

Comment: " от себя он выполняется" - это означает что права на выполнение выставлены. "#!/bin/bash" - это все прописано, здесь привел кусок кода