# Не выполняется скрипт symfony по крону

Tags: cron, symfony3

Если запустить скрипт на сервере вручную из консоли

php bin/console arfs:order

то, отрабатывает хорошо

но если он выполняется по крону, то ничего не работает
в логах крона вот такая строка после запуска скрипта

cron[5025]: (DKostin) MAIL (mailed 15 bytes of output but got status 0x0047)

скрипт с почтой не работает.
В чем проблема?

P.S. Попробовал выполнить скрипт с > /arfs.log 
Файл записался пустой

Comment: 1. от чьего имени выполняется cron-задание? 2. каталог `bin` (с файлом `console`) находится в домашнем каталоге вашего пользователя? попробуте указать явно этот путь: `php /путь/к/bin/console ...`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/619383/178576

Answer (score 0):

Вот [решение](https://askubuntu.com/questions/500749/cron-job-not-running-postfix-sendmail-error.) вашего вопроса.

> When executing commands, any output is  mailed  to  the  owner  of  the
>     crontab (or to the user named in the MAILTO environment variable in the
>     crontab, if such exists)

Когда выполняет команда , любой вывод отправляется владельцу крона ( или пользователю указанному в окружении MAILTO, если такой существует).

php bin/console arfs:order >> %путь к лог файлу% 2>&1  с указание уровня логирования.

Переменная MAILTO настраивается в systemd.cron. Попробуй её указать MAILTO=""
как сказано в документации.

> If MAILTO is defined but empty (MAILTO=""), no mail will be sent. 
>   Если переменная не указана отправляться письма не будут.

```
[Инструкция Cron][2]
```

Comment: не подскажешь где это проверить и исправить?